# Problems with hostmane: unrecognized service

Tags: networking, server

Already more than a month as I uninstalled Windows and I use Ubuntu 14 now.
But now I have little problem, but could not solve it alone.
I can not configure the sendmail
Before sendmail confuguration I need to configure hostname

I tried using command

```
RMK:~$ sudo hostname localhost
```

and I get bad response

```
sudo: unable to resolve host localhost
```

on the way `ls /etc/init.d`   file `hostname.sh`  is missing

command `sudo service hostname`
hostname responds me: unrecognized service

in `/ etc / hosts` I have is

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 RMK
```

in `/ etc / hostname`

```
localhost
RMK
```

Plese help me in my problem

Comment: (1) `hostname` isn't a service, so the fact that you can't run it as one does not indicate a problem (2) AFAIK there is no `hostname.sh` file, so I don't think that's a problem either. FYI the message `unable to resolve host localhost` is coming from the `sudo` command, rather than from the `hostname` command - perhaps it doesn't like having multiple entries in /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Each line in `hosts` should carry a unique IP. I believe replacing the two lines containing `127.0.0.1` with a single

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost RMK
```

will do the trick. That is, if you can `sudo`... If not, you need to boot a recovery system, mount your Ubuntu partition, and edit `hosts` from there.

---

The manpage of `hostname` is somewhat outdated for Ubuntu releases using upstart or systemd.

Instead of an init script `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh`, you can find e.g. an upstart config file `/etc/init/hostname.conf`. Query the service with `init status hostname`.